# Why is there so much "magic" in Perl?

Tags: perl

Looking through the [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) manpages I've noticed that there are many references to "magic" and "magical" there (just search any of them for "magic"). I wonder why is Perl so rich in them.

Some examples:

```
print ++($foo = 'zz')            # prints 'aaa'       
printf "%d: %s", $! = 1, $!      # prints '1: Operation not permitted'
while (my $line = <FH>) { ... }  # $line is tested for definedness, not truth
use warnings; print "0 but true" + 1  # "0 but true" is a valid number!
```

Comment: Perlmonks have a similar thread: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118492

Comment: Because Perl was created by a Great Wizard. http://www.wall.org/~larry/

Comment: I don't think your examples contain anything that the Perl documentation refers to as "magic" or "magical". Rather, they are examples of Perl's free syntax. What is it you specifically want to ask: why Perl's syntax is so free, why the terms "magic" or "magical" occur so often in Perl's documentation, or what the strictly technical use of those terms in the documentation refers to? Those are three very different questions. Which one do you mean to ask?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When a Perl feature is described as "magic":

> It means that that feature is
>   implemented by NBA star Magic Johnson.
>   Whenever Perl executes "magic", it is
>   actually sending an RPC call to a
>   remote receiver implanted in Magic
>   himself. He computes the answer, and
>   then sends a return message. The use
>   of Mr. Johnson for all the hard parts
>   of Perl provides a great abstraction
>   layer and simplifies porting to new
>   platforms. It's way easier than, say,
>   the Apache Portable Runtime.

Source: [perrin on Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118513)

It's official! Perl is more magical.

Hits from the following Google searches:

```
 25  site:ruby-doc.org     magic
 36  site:docs.python.org  magic
497  site:perldoc.perl.org magic
```

Answer (score 26):

Magic, in Perl parlance is simply the word given to attributes applied to variables / functions that allow an extension of their functionality.  Some of this functionality is available directly from Perl, and some requires the use of the C api.

A perfect example of magic is the `tie` interface which allows you to define your own implementation of a variable.  Every operation that can be done to a variable (fetching or storing a value for instance) is exposed for reimplementation, allowing for elegant and logical syntactic constructs like a hash with values stored on disk, which are transparently loaded and saved behind the scenes.

Magic can also refer to the special ways that certain builtins can behave, such as how the first argument to `map` or `grep` can either be a block or a bare expression:

```
my @squares = map {$_**2} 1 .. 10;
my @roots   = map sqrt, 1 .. 10;
```

which is not a behavior available to user defined subroutines.

Many other features of Perl, such as operator overloading or variables that can return different values when used with numeric or string operators are implemented with magic.  Context could be seen as magic as well.

In a nutshell, magic is any time that a Perl construct behaves differently than a naive interpretation would suggest, an exception to the rule.  Magic is of course very powerful, and should not be wielded without great care.  Magic Johnson is of course involved in the execution of all magic (see FM's answer), but that is beyond the scope of this explaination.

Comment: "which is not a behavior available to user defined subroutines" - no, that's what a leading & prototype does.

Comment: @ysth => i was referring to the way map and grep can take either syntax (as shown), whereas a sub with a leading & prototype requires a block or explicit code reference, and can not "capture" its first argument like map/grep/split and many other builtins.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert => that syntax will not capture the first argument unless it is `&subname`, which really only looks like its capturing it, since that prototype imposes reference context.  The case that only map/grep can do is `map $_**2, 1 .. 10`

Answer (score 15):

> I wonder why is Perl so rich in them.

To make things easy.

You'll find that most "magic" in Perl is to simplify the syntax for common tasks.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Perl seeks to shorten the syntax in order to make golfer's life easier.

Comment: Does anyone know of any cases of perl syntax being added specifically for golfing? :)

Comment: @LiraNuna: In a word, 'bullshit'. If anything, I would say that Perl's magic is aimed at making programmers happy (to paraphrase Ruby-creator and Perl fan Yukihiro Matsumoto).

Comment: @LiraNuna: No, Perl seeks to make easy things easy. This does not imply support for golfing. Note also that Anon. said the magic is there to *simplify* the syntax, not to *shorten* it.

Comment: Gosh, can't you guys take s joke? :)

Comment: @LiraNuna In general, yes: I love a good joke. On SO, when it comes to Perl, probably not. There are too many tedious Perl-bashers here. None of it's funny any more.

Answer (score 15):

Because `perl` *always* **D**oes **W**hat **I** **M**ean for some values of always.

Comment: And some values of "mean"!

Comment: ROFL... best use of "for some values" I've seen in a couple of years :)

Answer (score 4):

I think (opinion more than fact) that this has to do with the organic growth viewpoint that Perl's creator Larry Wall has with the Perl language. Python is a study in the opposite approach, whose style often makes Perl hackers cringe at the perception of being *forced* to conform to a stylistic regime.

Some of it has to do with Perl being designed to be "efficient" at writing quick scripts to do Perl*-ish* tasks, in both wall clock time, and in keystrokes. Some of it has to do with the [TMTOWTDI](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?tmtowtdi) mantra of Perl and its followers.

Programmers tend to be opinionated about Perl's frequent usage of "magic", for some it is an eye-straining visual cacophony of chaos and disrespect for orderliness (which harkens back to the days of computer [Priesthood](http://www.memagazine.org/backissues/membersonly/oct05/features/cassist/45.jpg) in white lab coats behind a glass window), for others it is a shining example of getting things done efficiently, if not always obviously to the novice or outsider.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's design philosophy is that simple things must be simple.  This sounds good,and to some extent it is.  However, there's a tradeoff involved:  Making **every** simple thing a one-liner results in tons of special case hacks to save a few lines of code.  Different people have different preferences regarding making simple operations within a language simple versus making the language specification simple.  Perl is at one extreme.  Java is at the other, at least among languages that people actually use.  Python and C# are somewhere in between.

Comment: Perl makes simple things simple ... until you need a dictionary of arrays, anyway.

Comment: @Matthew: Huh? A hash (Perl's name for what Python calls a dictionary) of arrays is trivial. e.g. `my %h = (a => [1..3], b => [4..6]);` Indeed, once you're comfortable with the basics of references it's easy to create arbitrarily complex data structures.

Comment: @Michael: Yes indeed ... once you're comfortable with references and their esoteric syntax: `@{$h{'a'}}`, `$h{'a'}->[2]`, etc.

Comment: @Matthew Sometimes you want a copy of reference `$h{a}` , and sometimes you want a copy of the element(s) in a reference `@{ $h{a} }` . Also `$h{a}->[2]` is better written as `$h{a}[2]`

Comment: @Brad - I must disagree here. Omitting "->" is IMHO Very Bad JuJu for non-golf purposes since it decreases readability. (I wonder if Conway said anything on the topic?)

Comment: DVK, I think you're in the minority. `$h{a}->[2]->[5]->{foo}` ... yuk! Anything other than the top level has to be a reference, and making it explicit makes it harder to read.

Comment: That can be spelled $h{a}[2][5]{foo} just because the other is so tedious.